# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions not being called

Tags: iphone

the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not being called when i 
launch via push notification on a multitasking OS4.1 3GS device. I just get
AppdidEnterForeground called. Is this the way it is on a multitasking device. The docs
don't say this. If it is not called how do i access the launchOptions dict.

Thanks

Comment: if its not getting called, but `applicationDidEnterForeground` is being called then the app is already running - what did you want to do?

Comment: ok, i think it must be in the background state but in running mode rather than suspended. I suppose if it was really suspended then it would get called. I'll check and post back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

is called if your app receives a notification while running, in the background or in the foreground.

If you read the applications applicationState-property you could figure out if your app was active while receiving this notification.

Comment: The method will be called when you launch the app by taping on the notification. Not at the moment of actual arrival of the Remote notification.